# Finding the xml escaped dash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regular expression to find dashes in an html in javascript.  The dashes in html pages sometimes may be xml escaped with the string value of `&ndash;`.  However, using regular expression to find this string is not working for some reason.

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).innerHTML;
var escapedDash     = /&ndash;/ig;
var foundEscapedDash = html.match(escapedDash);
alert(foundEscapedDash);
```

The regular experession, `/&ndash;/ig` does not result in any values. Nor does the regular expression `/-/i` find the escaped dash `&ndash;`

Does anyone know of a regular expression that can find the escaped dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `innerHTML` to a string with an entity, it converts it to the literal character. For example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '&ndash;'
alert(div.innerHTML.length); // 1, not 7 as may be expected
```

So you need to match the actual character `&ndash`, and to do that, you can use the [unicode literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Unicode_Escape_Sequences) representation. For "–", it's `\u2013`.

```
div.innerHTML.match(/\u2013/ig)
```

By the way, assuming the dash is the first character of the string, you can find the hex number `0x2013` for yourself with `div.innerHTML.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = '&ndash;hello world &ndash;';
var escapedDash = /(&ndash;+)/ig;

var foundEscapedDash = str.match(escapedDash);
alert(foundEscapedDash);
```